# How do I represent this query in one sql line?

Tags: sql

I have a table of 'Messages'. Each message has a time stamp. Is there an SQL way to ask the following?

"Select all messages from the message table ONLY if one or more of them is older than ten minutes"

I.e if no messages are older than ten minutes I want no results. If any are older than ten minutes I want all the results.

Is that when possible in a single query?

Thanks!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Many of them are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS` to see if there are such row older than 10 minutes:

```
select * from messages
where exists (select 1 from messages where localtimestamp - timestamp > 10)
```

The timestamp calculation differs depending on dbms, so you have to adjust that part.

Answer (score 0):

Self join with EXISTS

```
SELECT * FROM messages a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM messages b WHERE a.timestamp - b.timestamp > 10)
```